# Merge Sort not returning Appropriate values

Tags: java, array-merge

My merge sort program looks in theory correct for two numerically equivalent arrays but the values being returned are not in order and not at all appropriate. I receive three zeros at the end of the merged list and there not even included in any of the arrays.

```
public class Merge_Sort
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] a1 = new int[10];
        int [] b1 = {32, 26, 44, 87, 48, 51, 53, 89, 92, 1};

        a1[0] = 12;
        a1[1] = 36;
        a1[2] = 45;
        a1[3] = 52;
        a1[4] = 48;
        a1[5] = 24;
        a1[6] = 29;
        a1[7] = 98;
        a1[8] = 23;
        a1[9] = 32;

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        int[] merge = new int[a1.length + b1.length];

        while (i < a1.length && j < b1.length) {
            if (a1[i] < b1[j]) {
                merge[k] = a1[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                merge[k] = b1[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        for (int x : merge) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn about merge sort:  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/

Answer (score 1):

This is not merge sort, but only the merging step.
It assumes that the input arrays are already sorted, which is not the case in your example.

Also, it is not complete: what if you reach the end of an array? What happens to the remaining elements?

Comment: Then I suggest you read about mergesort. There is a ton of material online.

Comment: @JayLav There is no need to be aggressive :) We are all here to help (for FREE). Anyways, take two smaller length arrays and trace out the results of your `while` loop on a piece of paper. You will find out that the resulted array is not sorted. The while loop you have written works if and only if the input arrays are sorted in the first place. I suggest you read through the link I previously posted :)